# Complicated CSS selector in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

Is there a shorter method to wait for *complicated* selector?

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
     var aid = setInterval(function(){
        let block = $('div[class="asset"]:contains("Assets Folder")');

        if(block.length){
           clearInterval(aid);
           block.click();
           resolve();
        }

     }, 100);
  })
});
```

`page.waitFor()` throws an error:

> Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'div[class="asset"]:contains("Assets Folder")' is not a valid selector.

Comment: If i remember correctly, the `:contains()` selector only works with jQuery. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)

Comment: Ok, so maybe there is shorter workaround, without `evaluate + promise + setinterval` chain?

Comment: my approach is to use javascript to insert a value to role or name for better selection. Puppeteer currently only supports for selection of name and role.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### page.waitForFunction()

You can use [`page.waitForFunction()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args) to wait for a given function to return a truthy value.

Keep in mind that the [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector is part of the jQuery API and not a standard CSS selector.

Therefore, instead, you can wait until [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) element (at least one) in an array of nodes matching the selector has [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) which [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) the specified text and is present in the DOM:

```
await page.waitForFunction(() =>
  [...document.querySelectorAll('div[class="asset"]')].some(e => e.textContent.includes('Assets Folder'))
);
```

#### page.waitForXPath()

Alternatively, XPath includes a [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function, so you can use [`page.waitForXPath()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options) with a corresponding XPath expression to wait for your element to be added to the DOM:

```
await page.waitForXPath('//*[contains(text(), "Assets Folder")]/ancestor-or-self::div[@class="asset"]');
```